# dragover dataTransfer while using "on" trigger

Tags: jquery

I have solution which works and looks like this:

```
var dropZones = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-zone');

for (var i = 0; i < dropZones.length; i++) {
    dropZones[i].addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();
       e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    });
   ...
}
```

But I have to trigger it with "on" function in due of Ajax redraws. But it returns me *"Cannot set property 'dropEffect' of undefined"*

```
$(document).on('dragover', '.drop-zone', function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});
```

Do you have any ideas why is this happening and how should I do that to keep it working after ajax reload?

Answer (score 0):

I've found answer at [Jquery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). I have to use **originalEvent**

The right result is:

```
$(document).on('dragover', '.drop-zone', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
});
```